# A proof for the value of a complex integration.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Prove that

\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x - i\alpha)^2}dx = \sqrt{2\pi}.
\end{equation*}
How can I prove it using contour integration & residue theorem? could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: If I remember correctly: the trick is to take a contour with one side along the real line, the other along the line $Im(z) = -\alpha$.

Comment: The RHS should be $\sqrt{\pi}$ and not $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: you are right I will correct it @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: So the technique I THOUGHT would solve this using Integration by Parts failed, but a simple use of Euler's Formula worked here (using a bit of obvious symmetry). While my solution is a bit lengthier, it could be done by a Calc 1 student!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution uses differentiation under the integral.

Write$$f(\alpha)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-i\alpha)^2}dx.$$ Then$$\frac{df}{d\alpha}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty2i(x-i\alpha)e^{-(x-i\alpha)^2}dx=-i\int_{-\infty}^\infty-2(x-i\alpha)e^{-(x-i\alpha)^2}dx.$$The latter is just $$\left.-ie^{-(x-i\alpha)^2}\right|_{-\infty}^\infty=0.$$This shows that the integral does not depend on $\alpha$. It is a classical result that$$f(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{2\pi},$$which completes the proof.

Comment: Am I allowed to take differentiation under the integral?

Comment: @MathLover Yes, you are. It is true, however, that differentiation under the integral sign is subtler when dealing with improper integrals.

Comment: A careful application of Integration by Parts will also yield a similar proof

Comment: How? @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: @MathLover I'll post a proof later or tomorrow if you want. No time right now.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen  ok I am waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach: $e^{-z^2}$ is an entire function, hence its integral over the rectangle having its vertices at $-R,+R,+R+i\alpha,-R+i\alpha$ is simply zero. On the other hand the contribute given by the integral over the line segment from $R$ to $R+i\alpha$ (over line line segment from $-R+i\alpha$ to $-R$) is negligible for large values of $R$:

$$ \left|\int_{R}^{R+i\alpha}e^{-z^2}\,dz\right| = e^{-R^2}\left|\int_{0}^{i\alpha}e^{-z^2}e^{-2Riz}\,dz\right|\leq e^{-R^2}|\alpha|e^{|\alpha|^2}$$
hence it follows that for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(z\pm i\alpha)^2}\,dz = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-z^2}\,dz = \color{red}{\sqrt{\pi}}.$$

Comment: I liked this proof :)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the squared term and applying Euler's formula, we get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2+\alpha^2}e^{2xi\alpha}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2+\alpha^2}\cos(2ax)dx +i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2+\alpha^2}\sin(2ax)dx$$
The second integral clearly goes to $0$ by symmetry (odd function), so we just have to calculate
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2+\alpha^2}\cos(2ax)dx$$
At this point the problem is a classic Integration by Parts problem, which I leave to the OP

Comment: If you (the OP) can't figure this out, let me know and I'm more than glad to give hints :) (not that I've actually solved this, but I'm fairly confident that the idea I have will work)